# Post an XML String via PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, xml-parsing

I need to post an XML String to a URL endpoint. I am familiar with doing this via JavaScript, but not as much via PHP. I will eventually be adding WordPress Gravity Form variables to the data but for now and testing it statically.

I am getting a cURL error but am a little uncertain on how to fix it.

Here is the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php
/* print the contents of a url */
function print_r_xml($arr,$wrapper = 'EstimateRequest',$cycle = 1)
{
    //useful vars
    $new_line = "\n";

    //start building content
    if($cycle == 1) { $output = 'xmlRequest='.$new_line; }
    $output.= tabify($cycle - 1).'<'.$wrapper.'>'.$new_line;
    foreach($arr as $key => $val)
    {
        if(!is_array($val))
        {
            $output.= tabify($cycle).'<'.htmlspecialchars($key).'>'.$val.'</'.htmlspecialchars($key).'>'.$new_line;
        }
        else
        {
            $output.= print_r_xml($val,$key,$cycle + 1).$new_line;
        }
    }
    $output.= tabify($cycle - 1).'</'.$wrapper.'>';

    //return the value
    return $output;
}

/* tabify */
function tabify($num_tabs)
{
    for($x = 1; $x <= $num_tabs; $x++) { $return.= "\t"; }
    return $return;
}

$postStuff = array(
    'ReferralCode'=> 'ELE20590',
    'PrimaryContact'=>array(
        'Email'=>'hello@hello.com',
        'FirstName'=>'Test',
        'LastName'=>'Test',
        'HomePhone'=>'3035551234',
    ),
    'PickupAddress'=>array(
        'Address1'=>'410 17th St',
        'City'=>'Denver',
        'Zip'=>'80202'
    ),
    'MoveDetails'=>array(
        'PickupZip'=>'80202',
        'DeliveryZip'=>'DeliveryZip',
        'MoveDate'=>'5/1/2018',
        'DwellingType'=>'10'
    ),
    'Comments'=>'blah blah blah'
);
echo print_r_xml($postStuff);
$getPosts = print_r_xml($postStuff);
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://url-of-my-endpoint",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $getPosts,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

I can get this to work from PostMan just feeding it an XML string. but darned if I know how to get past this is PHP.

Here is the postman HTTP that works, that I am trying to emulate (with many more fields than are required...but you get the idea.

```html
POST /sirvaxmlfeed/requestanestimate.asmx/SendEstimateRequestXmlString HTTP/1.1 Host: ballpark.allied.com Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Cache-Control: no-cache Postman-Token: 370cade0-fafd-63fb-dd8e-25af2dfd00ab xmlRequest=
<EstimateRequest>

  <ReferralCode>ELE20590</ReferralCode>

  <PrimaryContact>

    <Email>sample@sample.com</Email>

    <FirstName>sample</FirstName>

    <LastName>sample</LastName>

    <PrimaryPhoneType>H</PrimaryPhoneType>

    <PreferredContactTime>A</PreferredContactTime>

    <HomePhone>3035551234</HomePhone>

    <WorkPhone>2223334444</WorkPhone>

    <WorkPhoneExt>112</WorkPhoneExt>

    <CellPhone>2223334444</CellPhone>

    <FaxPhone>2223334444</FaxPhone>

  </PrimaryContact>
  <PickupAddress>

    <Address1>410 17th St</Address1>

    <Address2></Address2>

    <City>Denver</City>

    <State>CO</State>

    <Zip>80202</Zip>

  </PickupAddress>

  <MoveDetails>

    <Process>True</Process>

    <PickupZip>80202</PickupZip>

    <DeliveryZip>80110</DeliveryZip>

    <MoveDate>5/1/2018</MoveDate>

    <DwellingType>A1</DwellingType>

    <AmountOfFurnishings>M</AmountOfFurnishings>

    <PickupShuttle>Y</PickupShuttle>

    <DeliveryShuttle>N</DeliveryShuttle>

    <AgentCode>2059000</AgentCode>

    <CalendarTitle>Bob’s Appointment</CalendarTitle>

    <CalendarLocation>West Wayne WASHINGTON, DC 20001 US</CalendarLocation>

    <CalendarAppointmentDate>12/13/2017</CalendarAppointmentDate>

    <CalendarAppointmentTime>09:00</CalendarAppointmentTime>

    <CalendarAppointmentTimeOfDay>AM</CalendarAppointmentTimeOfDay>

    <CalendarDuration>1 hour</CalendarDuration>
    <CalendarUserName>jodoe1234@gmail.com</CalendarUserName>

    <CalendarSalesPersonId>12345</CalendarSalesPersonId>

    <CalendarDetail>LMP Lead ID:1026861 Cust Name:Johny Test</CalendarDetail>

    <CalendarURL>
      <![CDATA[http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/jodoe1234@gmail.com/private/full/0qqbfbnjc7gr2hqa02ibua5irs]]>
    </CalendarURL>

  </MoveDetails>

  <EstimateDetails>

    <HasVehicles>Y</HasVehicles>

    <RequestedEstimateDate>3D</RequestedEstimateDate>

    <RequestedEstimateTimeOfDay>A</RequestedEstimateTimeOfDay>

    <SpecialtyItems>sample text</SpecialtyItems>

    <Comments>sample text</Comments>

    <HTTPUserAgent>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)</HTTPUserAgent>

    <VendorId>ABC123</VendorId>

    <VendorName>ABCD</VendorName>

    <VendorParms>aid=12345,sid=12345</VendorParms>

    <OptInForSpecialOffers>Y</OptInForSpecialOffers>

    <ThirdPartyOptIn>Y</ThirdPartyOptIn>

    <VendorDateTime>11/19/2015 11:30:00</VendorDateTime>

    <ReferrerFirstName>Jim</ReferrerFirstName>

    <ReferrerLastName>George</ReferrerLastName>

    <ReferrerEmail>leadfromLMP@email.com</ReferrerEmail>

    <MortgageDetails>

      <Process>True</Process>

      <LoanType>P</LoanType>

      <LoanAmount>300000</LoanAmount>

      <DownPayment>10</DownPayment>

      <CurrentInterestRate>5.25</CurrentInterestRate>

      <MortgageState>IL</MortgageState>

      <Comments>
        <![CDATA[No comments]]>
      </Comments>

      <CreditProfile>E</CreditProfile>

      <PreQualifiedForMortgage>Y</PreQualifiedForMortgage>

      <OfferCode>abc</OfferCode>

      <PreferredContactTime>M</PreferredContactTime>

      <ExistingHomeBalance>200000</ExistingHomeBalance>

    </MortgageDetails>

    <RealEstateDetails>

      <Process>True</Process>

      <TransactionType>X</TransactionType>

      <IsHomeListedForSale>Y</IsHomeListedForSale>

      <ExpirationDate>08/30/2015</ExpirationDate>

      <ApproximateSalePrice>285000</ApproximateSalePrice>

      <IsPreQualified>Y</IsPreQualified>

      <RealEstateState>IL</RealEstateState>

      <Comments>
        <![CDATA[No comments even now]]>
      </Comments>

    </RealEstateDetails>

    <HomeValue>

      <Process>True</Process>

      <CurrentHomeValue>285000</CurrentHomeValue>

      <NewHomeValue>330000</NewHomeValue>

      <AgencyNumber>AI2345</AgencyNumber>

      <SalesCode>SCP0079</SalesCode>

      <SalespersonName>Sales123</SalespersonName>

      <SalespersonEmail>Sales@123.com</SalespersonEmail>

    </HomeValue>
  </EstimateDetails>
</EstimateRequest>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this:

```
$_POST = array(
    'ReferralCode'=> 'ELE20590',
    'PrimaryContact'=>array(
        'Email'=>'hello@hello.com',
        'FirstName'=>'Test',
        'LastName'=>'Test',
        'HomePhone'=>'3035551234',
    ),
    'PickupAddress'=>array(
        'Address1'=>'410 17th St',
        'City'=>'Denver',
        'Zip'=>'80202'
    ),
    'MoveDetails'=>array(
        'PickupZip'=>'80202',
        'DeliveryZip'=>'DeliveryZip',
        'MoveDate'=>'5/1/2018',
        'DwellingType'=>'10'
    ),
    'Comments'=>'blah blah blah'
);
```

`$_POST` is a superglobal, you cannot set it as a variable like this.

This section will fail if `$cycle != 1` as you define $output within the `if` so you cannot append to it if it doesnt get set.

```
if($cycle == 1) { 
    $output = 'xmlRequest='.$new_line; 
}
$output.= tabify($cycle - 1).'<'.$wrapper.'>'.$new_line;
```

Same problem here, `$return` is not set:

```
function tabify($num_tabs) {
    for($x = 1; $x <= $num_tabs; $x++) { 
        $return.= "\t"; 
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I updated my original code using a different variable name etc...but the error remains.

Comment: I also added the postman http to the end of my original post.

Comment: Updated answer for you

Comment: yes you can set $_POST like that. its not a good idea, but your statement that `you can't do it` is wrong. an accurate statement would be something like `it's a bad idea to overwrite $_POST`